# Custom config section key

Tags: c#, web-config, app-config

I have implemented custom config section like this

```
 <directorySettings>
   <domainConfigurationList>
     <domainConfiguration id="1" name="name1" url="http://www.google.com"/>
     <domainConfiguration id="2" name="name2" url="http://www.bing.com"/>
   </domainConfigurationList>
 </directorySettings>
```

I can set only one field as key:

```
    protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
    {
        return ((DirectorySettingsConfigurationElement)element).Name;
    }
```

but I also need to have possibility to search using not only by key 'name' but also by field 'id'. Here is part of my `DirectorySettingsConfigurationElementCollection`:

```
    public DirectorySettingsConfigurationElement Get(string name)
    {
        return (DirectorySettingsConfigurationElement)BaseGet(name);
    }

    public DirectorySettingsConfigurationElement GetById(int id)
    {
        // ???
        return null;
    }
```

What is the best way to get my `DirectorySettingsConfigurationElement` by custom field (not by key)

Comment: Iterate the set of values until you have one with the matching ID. For small sets this will not be too expensive. (If you want to make it more performant for larger sets then you could employ a hashtable, e.g. Dictionary.)

Comment: Paul, how can I iterate it? There is no access to the element collection..

Comment: Solved! ConfigurationElementCollection has GetEnumerator method - I can use it to iterate

Comment: You need not call `GetEnumerator`: the type implements `IEnumerable` so you can use `foreach`. `foreach (ConfigurationElement elephant in blah) { ... }`.

Comment: Yes, in my case it would be  foreach(var item in this) { ... }

Answer (score 0):

There might be a more direct answer; but the way I've generally seen this done is by using a `ConfigurationElementCollection` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationelementcollection.aspx)

You'd get a collection of domainConfigurations and you'd be able to iterate across it or use a LINQ query to get the matching value.

Comment: Yes, this is actually the way I've sort it out, but it looks like workaround but not  solution.. Anyway - it works fine for me. Thank you